# analytical derivative of splinefun()

Tags: r, spline

I'm trying to fit a natural cubit spline to probabilistic data (probabilities that a random variable is smaller than certain values) to obtain a cumulative distribution function, which works well enough using `splinefun()`:

```
cutoffs <- c(-90,-60,-30,0,30,60,90,120)
probs <- c(0,0,0.05,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.9,1)
CDF.spline <- splinefun(cutoffs,probs, method="natural")
plot(cutoffs,probs)
curve(CDF.spline(x), add=TRUE, col=2, n=1001)
```

I would then, however, like to use the density function, i.e. the derivative of the spline, to perform various calculations (e.g. to obtain the expected value of the random variable).

Is there any way of obtaining this derivative as a function rather than just evaluated at a discrete number of points via `splinefun(x, deriv=1`)?

[This](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-March/101901.html) is pretty close to what I'm looking for, but alas the example doesn't seem to work in R version 2.15.0.

Barring an analytical solution, what's the cleanest numerical way of going about this?

Comment: What "doesn't work" ?  But, in the meantime, how about `curvefoo<-curve(CDF.spline(x), add=TRUE, col=2, n=1001)` followed by calculating the slopes of `curvefoo$y` vs `curvefoo$x` ?  You should have fine enough resolution that the local linear fits will give you a good vector of densities.

Comment: I was getting this error message: "Error in g(x) : object 'C_spline_eval' not found". Which seemed odd once I looked at the code for `splinefun` because 'C_spline_eval' was still obviously around  ... someplace. So changing the `environment()` call seemed like a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the environment assignment line for `g` in the code the Berwin Turlach provided on R-help to this:

```
environment(g) <- environment(f)
```

... you succeed in R 2.15.1.